# Run MATLAB script on cmd without opening the GUI window or the icon

Tags: matlab, user-interface, cmd, matlab-gui

I run the command below to execute a MATLAB script on the cmd, but **I don't want it to display the matlab window or the icon on the bare spot**,
what's the proposed solution?

`matlab.exe -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -minimize -r "cd G:\AARN\Script; try, run ('G:\AARN\Script\test.m'); end; quit "`

Comment: This works on Linux and MacOS, but of course Windows is different. My suggestion always is to switch to a real OS. :p

Comment: Take a look at the COM Automation feature: http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/call-matlab-com-automation-server.html